# watch is not detecting change when array is spliced , but watcher runs when the array is being populated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
@click="filter.organization.splice(index, 1)"
```

watch is ot detectng splice but works when the array is being populated

```
watch(
      () => filter.organization,
      (filter) => {
        console.log(filter, 'filter');
      }
    );
```

Comment: Hey, maybe you can see if this is the reason of your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74854103/vue-not-triggering-changes-inside-v-if-in-template-when-using-index/74860530#74860530

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you've used to create your watcher is specifically used to detect when `filter.organization` is **replaced**, not when **modified**. See the Vue [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) for more information.

To fire the watcher for every modification:

```js
watch(filter, (newfilter, oldfilter) => {
  console.log(newfilter);
});
```

or modify your current watcher to include the `deep` option

```js
watch(
  () => filter.organization,
  (filter) => {
    console.log(filter, "filter");
  },
  { deep: true }
);
```