# v-if not updating dynamically inside a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Solved -- solution at bottom of post**

I'm experiencing a problem in Vue2 where I'm trying to control a `v-if` & `v-else` based on an `@click` event inside a `v-for` loop, but the `v-if` is not changing dynamically each click like I would expect.

Here is roughly the code that is failing (note: `people` comes from a store file and is fully loaded when used):

```html
<div v-for="(person, index) in people" :key="index">
  <div @click="detailsOpened(index)">
    <PersonIcon v-if="showDetails(index)" />
    <PersonIcon2 v-else />
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import {
  each
} from 'lodash-es'

data(): {
  return {
    personMap: []
  }
}

beforeMount() {
  this.personMap = each(people, () => false)
}

methods: {
  showDetails(index: number): boolean {
    return this.personMap[index] === true
  }

  detailsOpened(index: number): boolean {
    return this.personMap[index] = !this.personMap[index]
  }
}
```

I've done `console.log` print outs and `detailsOpened` seems to work correctly. The boolean value keyed at each relevant index changes when the icon is clicked so that isn't the problem. It seems the `v-if` only runs when the page first renders and it doesn't update dynamically when the `personMap` values change. `console.log`'s confirm that the `showDetails` method only runs at the beginning of the page loading, based on the size of the `people` array. I'm not sure what is causing this and would appreciate any help in the right direction!

**Edit: Solution**
I had tried the top answer's advice but get hit with the console error, "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.". I moved these methods and data to a Pinia store file and explictly called "Vue.set"/"this.$set" in the store's setter and still got the the same error. What ultimately solved my problem was 1) Moving data and methods to a Pinia store file. 2) Using using `Vue.set` on the `detailsOpened` method inside the store file. 3) Using lodash's `cloneDeep` on `people` when `this.personMap` was initialized.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said: "showDetails method only runs at the beginning of the page loading". Vue doesn't know when to call the `showDetails` method again. A method must be called and executed explicitly in order to run.

In your case, you can use a computed property to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: A computed property does not work here bc it requires the function to use a parameter. I get an error in my IDE when trying to use a computed property that has a parameter like 'index', "TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Type '(index: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ComputedOptions<any> | (() => any)'.       Type '(index: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type '() => any'."

Answer (score 0):

Call it in computed instead of method

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(person, index) in people" :key="index">
    <div @click="detailsOpened(index)">
      <PersonIcon v-if="personDetailsOpen(index)" />
      <PersonIcon2 v-else />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      personMap: [],
      people: [...] // initialize with your data
    };
  },
  methods: {
    detailsOpened(index) {
      this.$set(this.personMap, index, !this.personMap[index]);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    personDetailsOpen() {
      return (index) => this.personMap[index] === true;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with that is I get an error in my IDE when trying to use a computed property that has a parameter like 'index', "TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Type '(index: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ComputedOptions<any> | (() => any)'.       Type '(index: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type '() => any'."

Answer (score 0):

**Vue does not react when you directly update the item at its index.** You need to use the **set operator** to make it reactive. Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74854103/vue-not-triggering-changes-inside-v-if-in-template-when-using-index/74860530#74860530) too for more understanding.

On another hand, here is a working demo of your use-case where I used a **set** to update the `personMap` array's item.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      people: [1, 2, 3],
      personMap: []
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.personMap = this.people.map(item => item = false);
  },
  methods: {
    showDetails(index) {
      return this.personMap[index] === true
    },
    detailsOpened(index) {
      this.$set(this.personMap, index, !this.personMap[index])
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(person, index) in people" :key="index">
    <div @click="detailsOpened(index)">
      <div v-if="showDetails(index)">Clicked</div>
      <div v-else>Click me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried this previously but get hit with the console error, "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.". I moved these methods and data to a Pinia store file and explictly called "Vue.set"/"this.$set" in the store's setter and I'm getting the same error